# Display DropDownList User Selections on Screen with a Separator - append or Join?

Tags: jquery

This code will display the user selections from the dropDowList on screen as they are selected.

Now I need to place a separator after each selection so they don't run together. I have tried the append as well as join but without success.

Would someone please show me how to accomplish this simple task?

```
$("#ServiceRequest_select").change(function() {
    var content = $("#ServiceRequest_select option:selected").text();
    $("TD#displayitem").text(content);
});
```

UPDATE: Jquery examples that aren't working:
The result of using Raminson's suggested code with `this` instead of the `div#` is that; Every item displays when a single item is selected and without seperation of items. I'm thinking it's because the jquery is in Yii's PHP. Thank you for trying Raminson.

```
$("#ServiceRequest_select").change(function() { 
    var content = $(this).text(); // text of selected option
    $("#displayitem").append("<span>"+ content +"</span>"); // appends a new span 
});
```

This next example, using the `div#` instead of `this` will show the selected items BUT it doesn't remove deselected items SO it adds the changed selection below previous selection.

```
$("#ServiceRequest_select").change(function() { 
    var content = $("#ServiceRequest_select option:selected").text();
    $("TD#displayitem").append("<span>"+ content +"</span>");
});
```

I have tried variations, searched for examples, but still need **help to display the user selections/deselections on the page with a serparator such as `<br />` as they are selected/deselected?** Geez, I'm going to need brain surgery; I'm glad I'm not trying anything REALLY complex! :smile: I still think Jquery is kewl!

Comment: Please provide more code. Most of the readers cannot make any connections to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#ServiceRequest_select").change(function() {
  var content = $(this).text(); // text of selected option
  $("#displayitem").append('<span class="new">'+ content +'</span>'); // appends a new span 
});
```

Comment: $("#ServiceRequest_select").change(function() {
    var content = $(this).text(); // text of selected option
    $("#displayitem").append("<span>"+ content +"</span>"); // appends a new span 
    });
Every item displayed when a single item was selected and without seperation of items.

Comment: $("#ServiceRequest_select").change(function() {
      var content = $("#ServiceRequest_select option:selected").text();
      $("TD#displayitem").append("<span>"+ content +"</span>");It doesn't remove deselected items; it adds new selection below previous selection.
   }); ');

Comment: **The second code works better but still has problem.**  as noted, it doesn't remove deselected items...  
arggg, sorry, didn't realize 5 minute limit on edit!  If someone wants to; fix it??